# AJAX function request stops previous load when called again - no jQuery please

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, load

I got this function to load an url into an element. The problem is that if I call it repetitively, like in a loop to load several elements, the current load stops:

```
function ajaxGetData(url, objId)
{
    var request;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
    { 
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } 
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) 
    { 
        try 
        {
            request = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
        } 
        catch (e) 
        {
        try {
            request = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        } 
        catch (e) {}
        }
    }

    if (!document.getElementById(objId))
    {
        return false;
    }
    var obj = document.getElementById(objId); /* <= fix: added var */
    ajaxLoadingIndicator(obj);

    request.addEventListener("progress", function(event){ajaxCallBack(event, obj)}, false);
    request.addEventListener("load", function(event){ajaxCallBack(event, obj)}, false);
    request.addEventListener("error", function(event){ajaxCallBack(event, obj)}, false);
    request.addEventListener("abort", function(event){ajaxCallBack(event, obj)}, false);

    request.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
        if(request.readyState === 4) 
        { 
            if(request.status === 200) 
            { 
                obj.innerHTML  = request.responseText;
            }
            else
            {
                obj.innerHTML = '<div id="'+id+'">Error loading data.</div>';
            }
        }
    };
    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send(null);
}

function ajaxLoadingIndicator(obj)
{
    idBase = obj.id.split("_");
    id = idBase[0]+"_ajax_loading";
    obj.innerHTML = '<div id="'+id+'">Loading</div>';
}

function ajaxCallBack(e) 
{
    // Handle each event
    switch(e.type)
    {
        case 'error':
        {
            idBase = obj.id.split("_");
            id = idBase[0]+"_ajax_error";
            obj.innerHTML = '<div id="'+id+'">Server unavailable. Error loading data.</div>';
        } break;
    }
}
```

So if I do:

```
ajaxGetData(url1, objId1);
ajaxGetData(url2, objId2);
ajaxGetData(url3, objId3);
```

Only objId3 gets its content, the rest get stuck in the "loading" indicator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a global variable `obj` in your code.

```
// function ajaxGetData(url, objId)
obj = document.getElementById(objId);
ajaxLoadingIndicator(obj);
```

All of your requests are sharing the same variable so that's why it appears that only the last request is completing. You can fix it using the `var` keyword in the declaration.

Comment: Outstanding. Thank you!