# AJAX not pulling on bluehost

Tags: javascript, ajax, shared-hosting

I have two simple pages.

test.php:

```
<div id="demo"></div>


<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "sse.php", true);
  xhttp.send();
}

var myVar = setInterval("loadDoc()", 2000);
</script>
```

sse.php

```
<?php
echo time();
?>
```

Problem is - in my private PC - it works perfect.
every 2 seconds, sse.php is pulling, and demo-div changes accordingly.

BUT, in my Bluehost website, same script - doesn't work.
it pulls one time (after two seconds) and that's it - no more.

Funny thing is, if i refresh the sse.php manually (in another tab)
the demo div content does change! 
I tried to figure out what's the issue, but i'm out of ideas.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I'm speculating, but look at the HTTP headers in the Network tab and consider the context of https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/

Comment: your interval function is false. try this: `var myVar = setInterval(loadDoc, 2000);`

Comment: GET requests cache.... That is how the web runs fast, headers show it is cached for the next 7 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further research - adding those lines in the top of my sse.php file and refresh this page, solved my problem. Thanks.

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");

echo time();
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem which I described here:

[AJAX function request stops previous load when called again - no jQuery please](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41656342/ajax-function-request-stops-previous-load-when-called-again-no-jquery-please)

Go get that code I wrote and check if works for you.

EDIT:

A call would be:

```
ajaxGetData('http://whateverurl.com', 'containerObjectId');
```

And the supporting functions:

```
function ajaxGetData(url, objId)
{
var request;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
{ 
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
} 
else if (window.ActiveXObject) 
{ 
    try 
    {
        request = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
    } 
    catch (e) 
    {
    try {
        request = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    } 
    catch (e) {}
    }
}

if (!document.getElementById(objId))
{
    return false;
}
var obj = document.getElementById(objId); /* <= fix: added var */
ajaxLoadingIndicator(obj);

/* YOU MAY NOT NEED TO ADD/USE EVENT HANDLERS */
request.addEventListener("progress", function(event){ajaxCallBack(event, obj)}, false);
request.addEventListener("load", function(event){ajaxCallBack(event, obj)}, false);
request.addEventListener("error", function(event){ajaxCallBack(event, obj)}, false);
request.addEventListener("abort", function(event){ajaxCallBack(event, obj)}, false);

request.onreadystatechange = function() 
{
    if(request.readyState === 4) 
    { 
        if(request.status === 200) 
        { 
            obj.innerHTML  = request.responseText;
        }
        else
        {
            obj.innerHTML = '<div id="'+id+'">Error loading data.</div>';
        }
    }
};
/* in my case i'm using asynch AJAX request (true) */
request.open('GET', url, true);
request.send(null);
}
/* YOU CAN GO AND SHOW FANCY LOADERS HERE */
function ajaxLoadingIndicator(obj)
{
idBase = obj.id.split("_");
id = idBase[0]+"_ajax_loading";
obj.innerHTML = '<div id="'+id+'">Loading</div>';
}

/* IF YOU DONT WANT EVENT HANDLERS, YOU DON'T NEED THE FOLLOWING FUNC */
function ajaxCallBack(e) 
{
// Handle each event
switch(e.type)
{
    case 'error':
    {
        idBase = obj.id.split("_");
        id = idBase[0]+"_ajax_error";
        obj.innerHTML = '<div id="'+id+'">Server unavailable. Error loading data.</div>';
    } break;
}
}
```

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Link-only answers are difficult to understand and are susceptible to become invalid if the website is down or not working. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can reproduce the most relevant portions of the link/blog you are referring to into this post itself.